pointcloud fusion of 4 intelrealsese depth camera
I'm having a robot that has intelrealsense 435d depth camera on all the four sides.How can i fuse pointcloud data from each depth camera to make a 360deg pointcloud of the environment around the robot.

Here is a complete discussion that mentions both intel step by step tutorial about the fusion and other commercial softwares.
https://support.intelrealsense.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12862158006675-Combine-two-rectified-point-clouds
